# RxJava doOnTerminate vs. doAfterTerminate

Tags: rx-java

What is the value of `doAfterTerminate` when we already have `doOnTerminate`?

In the official docs [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Observable-Utility-Operators), only `doOnTerminate` is listed.
Why?

Comment: The wiki contents are a bit old; we will try to get it updated to 2.x. For now, I've added a couple of missing operators to that page, including `doAfterTerminate`.

Comment: thanks a bunch @akarnokd :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to go to the [JavaDoc for v2](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/) to find the distinction. In [`doOnTerminate`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#doOnTerminate-io.reactivex.functions.Action-) it says:

> This differs from `doAfterTerminate` in that this happens *before* the `onComplete` or `onError` notification.

The [`doAfterTerminate`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#doAfterTerminate-io.reactivex.functions.Action-) docs don't have a similar note, although the "after" in the method name is pretty suggestive.